# Markov property of a random process (a solution of piece-wise deterministic equations)

Tags: probability-theory, markov-process

Consider a piece-wise deterministic (Markov!) process
\begin{eqnarray}
\dot{x}(t) & = & A_{\theta(t,x(t))}x(t)\\
x(0) & = & x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n \notag
\end{eqnarray}
where $\theta(t,x(t))\in S ={1,2,\cdots,N}$ is continuous time Markov chain(!) whose intensity is $\lambda_{ij}$ when $x(t)\in C_1$ and $\mu_{ij}$ when $x(t)\in C_2$. Here  $C_1,C_2 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$,  $C_{1}\cup C_{2}=\mathbb{R}^{^{n}}$ and  $C_{1}\cap C_{2}=\phi$,. It is some kind of piece-wise deterministic process, where $x(t)$ is random because of the randomness of $\theta(t,x(t))$. The transition rate of $\theta(t,x(t))$ is $\lambda_{ij}$ or $\mu_{ij}$ depending on the set to which $x(t)$ belongs to. Let $x(0)\in C_1$ and define the first exit times (which can be proved as stopping times) $\tau_1,\tau_2,\cdots$ as
$$
\tau_{1}=\mathrm{inf}\{t\ge 0 :\,x(t)\notin C_{1}\},
$$
$$
\tau_{2}=\mathrm{inf}\{t \ge \tau_{1}:\,x(t)\notin C_{2}\}
$$
and so on. If $x(t)$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$-adapted process. Is $\theta(t,x(t))$ is also $\mathcal{F}_t$-adapted process? Within each stochastic intervals $[0,\tau_1)$,  $[\tau_1,\tau_2)$ and so on, the process $\theta(t,x(t))$ intuitively seems a Markov process. Is there a way to prove this?

Comment: Why did you deface your question?

Comment: You are right. Because I still have doubts about the existence of the solution of the given system if both $C_1$ and $C_2$ are dense sets, (if this query is valid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, if I understood correctly your equations, you have that a switching linear system $\dot x = A_\theta x$ where $\theta\in[1;N]$ is a continuous Markov chain whose intensity matrix depends on whether $x\in C_1$ or $x\in C_2$. Under some regularity conditions on $C_1$ and $C_2$ this process is indeed Markovian and falls into the class of PDP: piecewise-deterministic Markov processes.

The easiest way to show that $(x,\theta)$ is Markov is to embed it within the general framework of [PDPs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise-deterministic_Markov_process). According to the linked article, M. Davis was the first to use this term - at least, he has a [very nice book on the topic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/041231410X). Anyways, all necessary definitions and conditions for Markovianity can be found in his apparently [first paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2345677) on PDP.

Now, w.r.t. $\theta$: $\theta_t := \theta(t,x(t))$ is not a Markov process by itself as its distribution clearly depends on the value of $x(t)$.

Comment: thanks for the response. As you said $\theta(t,x(t))$ is not a Markov process in general, but only in the stochastic intervals as defined in my question. I will go through the references. Thanks a lot